# I have updated my Amazon Author bio but Google search is still showing the old bio. How can I get this to update?

Tags: google, amazon

I have updated my Amazon Author bio but Google search is still showing the old bio (although when I click on the link, it takes me to the new and correct Amazon page). How can I get the front page of Google to update?

Comment: What does "front page of Google" mean?   You can't be on Google's home page.

Comment: Sorry, I meant when I search for my name on Google - the very first result.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a site you control. This is a Amazon user question. Questions asked here are about web sites you either own or control. Your being able to create a page does not suffice.